# active tab issue in angular 2 - tabs

Tags: javascript, json, angular, tabs

Need help to fix the active tab issue in angular 2 application.

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/Bc4XbH7jdKc65jO5Hmjn?p=preview)**

I am loading tabs and respective information from json.

i have complex json format, but here i have made simplied version.

**Issue :** Active tabs are not set in the initial stage.

**Expected:** First tab **'Tab 1'** need to have **active** class.

**Please note:** on the click of tabs, *active class* is already added.
so need to fix active tab for the **first element**. so we should interfere other functionalities.

Any help is appreciated.

**Json**

```
[
      {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Tabs 1",
        "content": [
          {
            "header": "Basic Information",
            "contents": [
              {
                "label": "Report 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tabs 2",
        "content": [
          {
            "header": " Information",
            "contents": [
              {
                "label": "Report 2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Tabs 3",
        "content": [
          {
            "header": " report",
            "contents": [
              {
                "label": "Report 3"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "id": "4",
        "name": "Tabs 4",
        "content": [
          {
            "header": " content Report",
            "contents": [
              {
                "label": "Report 4"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

**app-service.ts**

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response }     from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';

@Injectable()

export class DashboardService {
  private _url: string = "./app/report.json";

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  getRecords() {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())

  }

  _errorHandler(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error || "Server Error");
  }

}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import {Component,ContentChildren,QueryList, OnInit, 
Injectable, Inject} from '@angular/core';
    import {TAB_COMPONENTS} from './tabset';
    import {Tab} from './tab';
    import { DashboardService } from './app-service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: `
            <h2>App Component</h2>
         <tabset>
          <tab *ngFor="let tab of records" [title]="tab.name"> 
            <div *ngFor="let header of tab.content">
            {{header.header}}
            <div *ngFor="let label of header.contents">{{label.label}}</div>
            </div>
          </tab>
        </tabset>
        `
    })
    @Injectable()
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      records = [];
      errorMsg: string;

      constructor(@Inject(DashboardService) private _dashboardService: DashboardService) {
        //this.getRecords();
      }

      // getting json values from report.json
      // To build the form
      ngOnInit() {
        this._dashboardService.getRecords()
          .subscribe(
            resGetRecords => {
              debugger;

              this.records = resGetRecords

            },
            resRecordsError => this.errorMsg = resRecordsError
          );
      }
    }
```

**tab.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: `
    <ng-content *ngIf="active"></ng-content>
  `
})
export class Tab {

  @Input() title = '';
  @Input() active = false;
  @Input() disabled = false;

}
```

**tabset.ts**

```
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  Output,
  ContentChildren,
  HostListener,
  EventEmitter
} from '@angular/core';

import { Tab } from './tab';

@Component({
  selector: 'tabset',
  template: `
    <section class="tab-set">
      <ul
        class="nav"
        [class.nav-pills]="vertical"
        [class.nav-tabs]="!vertical">
        <li
          *ngFor="let tab of tabs"
          [class.active]="tab.active">
          <a
            (click)="tabClicked(tab)"
            class="btn"
            [class.disabled]="tab.disabled">
            <span>{{tab.title}}</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
      </div>
    </section>
  `
})
export class Tabset {

  @Input() vertical;
  @Output() onSelect = new EventEmitter();
  @ContentChildren(Tab) tabs;

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    const tabs = this.tabs.toArray();
    const actives = this.tabs.filter(t => {
      return t.active
    });

    if (actives.length > 1) {
      console.error(`Multiple active tabs set 'active'`);
    } else if (!actives.length && tabs.length) {
      tabs[0].active = true;
    }
  }

  tabClicked(tab) {
    const tabs = this.tabs.toArray();

    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    tab.active = true;

    this.onSelect.emit(tab);
  }

}

export const TAB_COMPONENTS = [
  Tabset,
  Tab
];
```

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Hi, i am using angular 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**It would work if you are not loading data from a json, I meant there are an async  behaviour which you need to wait before.**

At the first time, you initialize the tab with an empty array  `records = [];` (in **app.component.ts**)

In the tabset component, in your **ngAfterContentInit**, you only check the first tabs data which in this time is an empty array,  and initialize the tabset with the first tab, which in this time is **undefined**. So no tab are set to active, that's why there are no selected tab.

And the tab data will updated with the right content ((with the 4 items from json)) only when the JSON data are loaded, after subscribing to the http, and there are no action to check and set the default selected tab.

So your solution is to subscribe on the change in the tabs before setting the selected tab:

```
ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.tabs.changes.subscribe((changes)=> {
      const tabs = this.tabs.toArray();
      const actives = this.tabs.filter(t => {
        return t.active
      });

      if (actives.length > 1) {
        console.error(`Multiple active tabs set 'active'`);
      } else  {
        this.tabClicked(tabs[0]);
      }
    });       
}
```

**ADDITION:**

if you have an error like:

```
Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.
```

You need to add `setTimeout()`  described in [the angular doc here](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#!#parent-to-view-child)

> The ngAfterViewInit() lifecycle hook is an important wrinkle. The
>   timer component isn't available until after Angular displays the
>   parent view. So it displays 0 seconds initially. Then Angular calls
>   the ngAfterViewInit lifecycle hook at which time it is too late to
>   update the parent view's display of the countdown seconds. Angular's
>   unidirectional data flow rule prevents updating the parent view's in
>   the same cycle. The app has to wait one turn before it can display the
>   seconds.
>
> Use setTimeout() to wait one tick and then revise the seconds() method
>   so that it takes future values from the timer component.

So now:

```
tabClicked(tab) {
    const tabs = this.tabs.toArray();
    tabs.forEach(tab => tab.active = false);
    setTimeout( () => tab.active = true);
    this.onSelect.emit(tab);
}
```

Working plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AZpieA3kow3xGT8UCIaj?p=preview

Comment: Great explanation. thank you for working on this. its working now.

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT:* the answer is finally not similar to your problem I think. Sorry.

-- IF you work with angular 4 --

You can see a similar [issue that I have reported](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19167).

There is an hack to make it work:

```
[routerLinkActive]="['']" [ngClass]="rla.isActive?'active':''" #rla="routerLinkActive"
```

Comment: thanks . as you mentioned its not helping with angular 2